# How do I convert a float to an integer in Elixir

Tags: elixir

Given a float, say (2.0), I want to convert it to an Integer type. It looks like Integer.parse only works for strings as far as I can tell.

```
Integer.parse(2.0)
(FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Integer.count_digits/2
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

To summarize the different answers listed on this question, there are good four options as of writing this: `trunc/1`, `round/1`, `floor/1`, and `ceil/1`. All accept both floats and integers.

#### trunc/1

Removes the decimal part of a float.

```
iex> trunc(2.3)
2
iex> trunc(-2.3)
-2
```

#### round/1

Rounds to the nearest integer.

```
iex> round(2.3)
2
iex> round(2.7)
3
iex> round(-2.3)
-2
iex> round(-2.7)
-3
```

#### floor/1

Always rounds down. Available as of Elixir 1.8.0.

```
iex> floor(2.3)
2
iex> floor(-2.3)
-3
```

#### ceil/1

Always rounds up. Available as of Elixir 1.8.0.

```
iex> ceil(2.3)
3
iex> ceil(-2.3)
-2
```

Comment: Changed the accepted answer to this one since my brain remembers floor() a lot easier than trunc(). It's the most similar to other programming languages

Comment: @AnilRedshift floor() returns unexpected value with negative number, in your problem(you need integer part not floor), e.g: floor(-4.2) will return -5 but you expect -4.

Comment: @AminSoheyli you make a very good point. I'll change this answer to reflect the different options with `trunc/1`, `round/1`, `floor/1`, and `ceil/1`.

Answer (score 43):

Use `trunc(2.0)` or `round(2.0)`. Those are auto-imported since they are part of [Kernel](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.html) and they are also allowed in guard clauses.

Comment: FWIW:  `round/1` still returns a Float at this point -- `trunc/1` will convert to Integer.

Answer (score 2):

Use `trunc(number)` function which is a Kernel function and auto-imported.

Elixir [Docs](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.html#trunc/1) of this function:

> Returns the integer part of number.

---

Examples:

```
trunc(5.4)    -->    5

trunc(-5.99)  -->   -5

trunc(-5)     -->   -5
```